# Hiding folder .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I need to hide a folder from a url.

An example:

If I enter www.mysite.com/jango.php I need you to read the directory: www.mysite.com/users/jango.php but do not want to see /users
I just want to see this in the address bar: www.mysite.com/jango.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use mod_rewrite

For you example rule will

```
RewriteRule ^jango\.php$ /users/jango.php
```

Comment: and if I wanted all the files inside the folder?

Comment: Then rewrite all files from server root to folder users. For example RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /users/$1.php  But it need debug

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/users/([^/]*)$ /$1 [L]
```